# Return True if any one of the Thread has returned True in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

**Note: The example provided below is just a placeholder to mimick the real situation. I want to understand the way to solve the problem so I can actually solve the real problem statement.**

Consider the below code:

I have two functions. They both need to run simultaneously. 
They check some conditions. If the condition is true they return True. If not they keep checking till 6 pm.

I want to trigger a function as soon as any one function returns True.

Note: I do not want to wait for the other process to finish. If func1() returns True, main should immediately return True.

I am using threading to run them simultaneously. I am very new to it so I can't write the termination condition.

I want to return a tuple that indicates if a condition is met and in which function using one of the three values: 
`(True, 'func1')`, `(True, 'func2')`, `(False, '')`

Code:

```
import threading
import datetime
import time
import random


def func1():
    # Do something here
    
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    
    while current_time < datetime.time(17, 37):
        
        rand_int = random.randint(1, 10)
        
        print(f"func1: {rand_int}")
        
        if rand_int == 1:
            print('func1 return True')
            return True
        
        time.sleep(8)
        
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        
    print('func1 return False')
    return False
    

def func2():
    # Do something else here
    
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time
    
    while current_time < datetime.time(17, 37): 
        
        rand_int = random.randint(1, 10)
        
        print(f"func2: {rand_int}")
    
        if rand_int == 10:
            print('func2 return True')
            return True
        
        time.sleep(8)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

    print('func2 return False')
    return False
    

def main():
    # Start both functions at the same time
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    # Wait for either function to return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`concurrent.futures` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), and in particular the `concurrent.futures.as_completed` method (there are examples in the docs).

Comment: Each of your two threads appears to [_poll_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) for the expected condition. That is to say, it continually checks, and then sleeps, checks and then sleeps,... They're even both sleeping for the same amount of time. So why have two threads? Why can't one thread check both conditions and then sleep?

Comment: P.S., It never makes any sense to create _one_ thread and then immediately wait for it to finish. So, for that matter, why create any new threads at all? Why can't your `main()` function just loop, checking the two conditions until one of them becomes true?

Comment: The two functions are just a placeholder.  In actual problem, I am solving something more complex. I will call a diff API in each function and then check for the condition. If the condition fails, I will wait 1 min and call the api again for a new response.

Comment: Also, both functions will have retracement_time which will depend on the API response. Let's say func1 is waiting for 26 mins and func2 is waiting for 12 mins. I can't do them sequentially.  If I wait 26 mins for func1, then my func2 is not checking response in real time.

Comment: Re, "If the condition fails, I will wait..." So, that's polling. Re, "I can't do them sequentially..." Yes. You _could_ do it if you wished to do. The trick is; to keep track of when you next need to wake up to perform task A, and when you need to wake up to perform task B, figure out which of the two wake up times is sooner, and calculate how long you need to sleep to wake up at that time. Basically, I'm describing a rudimentary [_scheduler_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)).

Comment: Normally, I would not advocate re-inventing something that's available from a library (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), but if I were faced with the problem you describe, I probably _would_ "re-invent" scheduling in order to avoid creating any new threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your code but i think this will help

code:

```
def main():

    a = ()

    # Start both functions at the same time
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    if thread1 == true:
        a = a + (true,"thread1")
    elif thread2 == true:
        a = a + (true,"thread2")
    else:
        a = a + (false, " ")

    print(a)
```

this is a really simple concept of conditions in this code I created a tuple named 'a' and I checked if the conditions of any thread has returned true if yes then add 'true' and '(function name)' and if none of the function returned true add 'false' and '(empty space)'
and after that I printed a. There is a better way to do this but you said that you were a beginner so I tried to make it as simple as possible. Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping out the community! Can you add some more description to your answer to explain how you expect the code to answer the OP's question? Future readers will also benefit from more explanation